# functional dependencies

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the schema R(ABEFJK) with functional dependencies 
    {BE->JK, J->FA, F->B}.

I was told to find all the keys for this function this is what I did I dont know if im correct

```
BE->JK
BE -> J  BE -> K
BE->FA BE->F {ABEFJK}
BE is a Key


F->B
FE->BE
FE->JK FE->J FE->K
FE->FA
FE->B
FE is a key

BE->JK
BEF->JKF BEF->JK
BEF->FA BEF->F
BEF->B
BEF is a key
```

Comment: as per my calculations your answer appears to be fine..BEF is union of other keys so obviously is a key